# searching an arrayList for a specific input to make a smaller arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Looking for startup input. I have a program where there are two arrayLists, one for book and one for author. The arrayList for books also has the author listed as an element within the arrayList. I need to find and print all of the books written by a single, hard-coded author (Ayn Rand). What would be the easiest way to go about this?

To load the respective ArrayLists, i'm doing it this way:

```
ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>(); 
authors = loadAuthors(); 
ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(); 
books = loadBooks(authors);
```

Book Class has following data members:

```
class Book{
    private String title; 
    private int copyright;
    private int edition; 
    private String isbn; 
    private ArrayList<Author> authors;
    ...
    } 

 class Author{
    private int id;
    private String first;
    private String last;  
    private static int nextNum=1;
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Are both of the lists `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: Do you have any problem statement? I believe you might be having a hashmap of String as key and ArrayList of string as value. Please recheck

Comment: Sorry--let me add to this. Here are the two statements within my driver that set up the arrayLists:
  ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
  authors = loadAuthors();
  ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
  books = loadBooks(authors);

They come from two classes, one Book, one Author.

Comment: What are the data members of `Book` and `Author` class?

Comment: Book has  private String title;
 private int copyright;
 private int edition;
 private String isbn;
 private ArrayList<Author> authors;
And author has  private int id;
 private String first;
 private String last;
 private static int nextNum=1;

Comment: Does `Book` class contain getter methods?

Comment: Yes the Book class contains getters and setters for every field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200136/discussion-between-shawn-benson-and-taurus05).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result by doing something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
 // There is no use of this arraylist, if the author you're looking for is hard-coded
 ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>(); 
 authors = loadAuthors(); 
 ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(); 
 books = loadBooks(authors);

 // iterate over the arraylist of Books
 for(Book b : books){ 
  // Get all the authors for the current Book obj
  ArrayList<Author> bookAuthors = b.getAuthors();

  // Iterate over the author's of that specific book arraylist 
  for(Author ar: bookAuthors){

   // Match condition that must be satisfied.
   if(ar.getFirst().equals("Ayn") && ar.getLast.equals("Rand")){

     // Do something here, like printing the book written by Ayn, or something else
     System.out.println(b.getTitle());
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) to concisely filter items from a list. For example:

```
ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>(); 
authors = loadAuthors(); 
ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(); 
books = loadBooks(authors);

Predicate<Book> byAuthorName = book ->
    book.getAuthors().stream().anyMatch(author -> 
        author.getFirst().equals("Ayn") &&
        author.getLast().equals("Rand")
    );

List<Book> result = books
   .stream()
   .filter(byAuthorName)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I don't know that this is quite what I was going for. But I appreciate the help regardless!

Comment: @ShawnBenson I edited my answer to better illustrate your scenario. Is not this type of list filtering you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ShawnBenson Made a further edit, considering that a book has multiple authors.